# Sanity check (MD5 sums) fails after joining a file

Tags: cat, split

I'm having a problem passing a sanity check, when combining a split file back to its original state even if it tarred with atime-preserve. Example below.

```
filename=FILENAME
newfilename=FILENAME2
md5precheck=$(md5sum $filename|awk '{print $1}')
split -b 3276800 -d $filename $filename.
cat $filename.* > $newfilename
md5postcheck=$(md5sum $newfilename|awk '{print $1}')
if [ $md5precheck == $md5postcheck ]
then
    echo "MD5 integrity check successful"
else
    echo "MD5 integrity check FAILED"
exit 1
fi
```

Comment: `equ` isn't a valid test operator. Use `=` for strings. Please update if that's just a typo you made posting here (and add the OS & version of split you're using).

Comment: Linux 4.3.0-10-generic armv6l
VERSION="December 2015"
VERSION_ID="2015.12-3"
ID=generic
ID_LIKE=debian

This is a Pi

Comment: The split commands is working as intended since if you use the cut command you just search for the last delimiter.

Comment: $ split --version
split (GNU coreutils) 8.23
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by Torbjorn Granlund and Richard M. Stallman.

Comment: cat $filename.* works fine for me I'm seeing raw data pass by so I am not sure what you are talking about. Can you elaborate, maybe an example. 
and I am adding the dot . for a reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@veggieVampire
Please always debug script with 'sh -x bash_script.sh' , I fount when the script runs on bash it send command like following.

```
+ cat 'FILENAME.*' 
cat: FILENAME.*: No such file or directory
```

use `sh -c "cat $filename.* > $newfilename"`  on 5th line insted of `cat $filename.* > $newfilename`

And again this script cannot be use for text file because when we use 'split' command.
All the text lines were spliting to each file in a sluggesh manner. If you cat the file you can see that.

Thanks.

Comment: working great thanks @Miralibabub
finished
https://github.com/VeggieVampire/PPscp